# Install FFmpeg on Debian with 'apt'

Tags: apt, software-installation, ffmpeg

I have a Debian Linux server (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (Jessie)) and want to install FFmpeg.

I do the following steps:

```
apt update
apt install ffmpeg
```

I then get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You already have answers. Allow me to also suggest the ffmpeg wiki page as a resource: https://wiki.debian.org/ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t jessie-backports ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously ffmpeg is not present in jessie, which is also oldoldstable release, partially covered by ELTS, but officially not supported by Debian anymore:
https://wiki.debian.org/LTS
https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended

For multimedia stuff it would make sense to update at least to stable. Or attempt to backport ffmpeg to jessie from stretch - oldstable.

Comment: how can I update to stable? I am afraid of breaking stuff.

Comment: what is this server is doing? what services are there?

Comment: running a torrent-software (transmission), nginx with a small wordpress-website, php. nothing super special.

Comment: well, I'd suggest to first update to stretch - oldstable, however the new version of php in stretch is 7.0 as far as I see, and in jessie it is still 5.0, I don't know if your website can survive that. but in any case running unsupported distribution is a bad idea

Comment: thanks for your advice